# Apache don't start in Uwamp 3.1 under

Tags: apache, uwamp

Apache does not want to start, while mySql OK.
I am running Uwawp 3.1 since a few weeks. No change in configuration.
My PC is under Windows 10.
This is a new problem, maybe just after a big update of windows 10.

No message to understand where it blocks.

How can i solve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem, on Win7 and portable distribution of uWamp.

uWamp was worked previously,

```
    1- i was copy the folder on a "backup"
    2- reinstalled Win7 ( with some windows updates ), and redist vc11
    3- now uWamp - apache won´t work, no messages, no logs just crash
```

### SOLUTION!!!!

I have resolved my problem by installing vc11 x86 from here 
https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=30679

How to found...
By executing uWamp/bin/apache/apache.exe a message apears that tell MSVCR110.dll is not found.

And http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db?auth=1 >> Yaqub K answers tell about solution.

Thats all folks!!!

sorry about my english... ;)

Comment: I can´t comment others so i put a new message, sorry ;-(

Comment: thanks, installing vc11 x86 solved the problem, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score 7):

> How to found... By executing uWamp/bin/apache/apache.exe a message apears that tell MSVCR110.dll is not found.

This is good advice.
After that, I looked for the `MSVCR110.dll` because installation of Visual Studio 2012 did not solve the problem.
Just put it in the `apache/bin` directory and it works.

Comment: yes, we have to install vc11 x86 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679